# React-Native: How to mark part of a picture, using coordinates and Image zoom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just started learning React-Native, I have such a problem in my current project.
I am receiving Car part image from API, this image is `png` format, each part number is numbered in the picture, I also getting coordinates (coordinates(x,y), width, height) of each number. My aim is to give border and border color each number inside part picture
The problem is that these coordinates are calculated on a full-sized image, and do not match the image on mobile devices. Also the problem arises when enlarging the image, the existing coordinates are almost useless.
I will accept any offer which will give me the right point, Thanks

I want to achieve same result, but I have no idea how they are solving this problem into an existing project: [link here](https://www.parts-catalogs.com/us/demo/#/parts?groupId=IzPwn5qAMTFfNDQ3MA&groupsPath=MfCfmoAxMQ&catalogId=bmw&carId=1f34ddc8b4e4c08550d62ff8cadebd89&q=WBAVM5C5XDVV90275&criteria=1c%2AWBAVM5C5XDVV90275%7E1355747730%21c16f6b53%7DVM53%5E50%3C20121200)

Reproduction Link: [link here](https://snack.expo.dev/@quji06/great-pretzels)

```js
import React from "react";
import { Animated, Dimensions, View, Image, Text} from "react-native";
import ImageZoom from 'react-native-image-pan-zoom';
import {useState} from "react";

const PinchableBox = () => {
    const [scale, setScale] = useState('')
    /* Part number, coordinates(x,y, width,height) */
    let partPosition = {number:1,coordinates:[327,18,12,22]}
     
    let calculated = partPosition.coordinates[0] / scale
    console.log(calculated)
    return (
        <View>
            <View style={{position:'relative'}}>
                <ImageZoom 
                    cropWidth={350}
                    cropHeight={290}
                    panToMove={true}
                    minScale={1}
                    maxScale={4}
                    imageHeight={300}
                    onMove={(e)=>setScale(e.scale)}
                    imageWidth={300}
                    style={{marginTop:0}}
                    >
                    <Image style={{ width: '100%', height: 300}}
                        source={{ uri: `https://img.parts-catalogs.com/bmw_2020_01/data/JPG/209412.png` }}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                    />
                </ImageZoom>
                <Text 
                style={{
                  color:'red', 
                  borderWidth:2, 
                  height:partPosition.coordinates[3], 
                  width:partPosition.coordinates[2],
                  position:'absolute',
                  transform:[{translateX:327 * (scale / 2 )},{translateY:18 * scale}]
                }}
                >{partPosition.number}
                </Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default PinchableBox;
```

Comment: The simple answer is just to scale the coordinates according to the scale of the image. The catch though, is to know the current image scale. Does the `<ImageZoom>` component expose the current scale?

Comment: @tromgy `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-pan-zoom` , As I saw in documentation it's not support current scale number, also other resizers does't supports this option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Dimensions, View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';
import ImageZoom from 'react-native-image-pan-zoom';
import { useState } from 'react';

const PinchableBox = () => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState('');
  const transformScale = { width: 300/800, height: 300/500 };
  // 800 is the actual image width and 300 is width shown in screen. Same for height.
  /* Part number, coordinates(x,y, width,height) */
  const [textPosition, setTextPosition] = useState({
    x: 315*transformScale.width,
    y: 80*transformScale.height,
  });
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(false);
  let partPosition = {
    number: 1,
    coordinates: [315, 80, 20, 20],
  };

  const checkIfClickLiesInAnyPart = ({ x, y }) => {
    const tX = x/transformScale.width;
    const tY =y/transformScale.height;
    let c=partPosition.coordinates;
    if(tX<=c[0]+2*c[2] && tX>=c[0]-2*c[2] && tY<=c[1]+c[3] && tY>=c[1]-c[3]) return {matchedWith:1};
    return {matchedWith:false};
  };
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('clicked', e);
    const {matchedWith}=checkIfClickLiesInAnyPart({ x: e.locationX, y: e.locationY })
    if (matchedWith) {
      setShowText(true);
      setTextPosition({ x: partPosition.coordinates[0]*transformScale.width, y: partPosition.coordinates[1]*transformScale.height });
    } else {
      setShowText(false);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <ImageZoom
          cropWidth={300}
          cropHeight={300}
          panToMove={true}
          minScale={1}
          maxScale={4}
          imageHeight={300}
          onMove={(e) => setScale(e.scale)}
          imageWidth={300}
          style={{ marginTop: 0 }}
          onClick={handleClick}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: '300px', height: '300px' }}
            source={{
              uri: `https://img.parts-catalogs.com/bmw_2020_01/data/JPG/209412.png`,
            }}
            resizeMode="contain"
          />
          // put textbox inside ImageZoom so that it also zooms / moves with image
          {showText && (
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'red',
                borderWidth: 2,
                height: '20px',
                width: '20px',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: textPosition.x + 'px',
                top: textPosition.y + 'px',
              }}>
              1
            </Text>
          )}
        </ImageZoom>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PinchableBox;
```

updated demo: [snack.expo.dev/i5IPPbFu4](https://snack.expo.dev/i5IPPbFu4)
[if you click near part1, the box will be highlighted else it'll be hidden...you can modify acceptable click area too]

I have left some comments too. The sample code is for 1 part only..for multiple parts modify `checkIfClickLiesInAnyPart` to check for all plus some other modifications.

Comment: Hi, problem is `let partPosition = {number:1,coordinates:[327,18,12,22]}` is dynamic value, it'should be exactly same, I dont understant how you get this coordinates `  let partPosition = {number: 1, coordinates: [315, 80, 20, 20]};`

Comment: I changed it a bit to perfectly align the Text 1 to letter 1 on image..but still whatever coordinates you get, the logic would remain same. The textbox would render at the coordinates provided.

Comment: No Sir, with this coordinates result is different `coordinates: [327,18,12,22]`, box is not showing

Comment: the box is showing if you click a bit above the 1 mark in the picture...

Comment: just noted that `resizeMode` is interfering with the logic..if you make resizeMode as stretch then it works fine with ur coordinates...but with resizeMode contain, the aspect ratio of image is mainted as it is hence the image is not scaling completely to 300px in height

Comment: updated demo: https://snack.expo.dev/i5IPPbFu4